# EA- Add model template to package wizard

Tags: wizard, enterprise-architect

I would like to create a generic structure of packages, that will be applied at the new-package wizard, as an offered template.

How can I add the new xmi file to the wizard? I use EA 12.

[image: Model wizard]

Comment: You need to include the pattern in your MDG. There are some threads on Sparx' forum dealing with that topic.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, I indeed import it to the model. It appears under the MDG Technologies package, but does not seem to be in the model wizard. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be that you need to drag-and-drop if you're using the Resources window (after following the steps in "Import MDG Technologies to Model"). I recommend following "Access Remote MDG Technologies" instead. This might make a difference, not sure.

Comment: You probably should cross post on Sparx' forum. MDG can easily become a PITA but with a bit of luck one of the Sparxians can help.

Comment: @Uffe, Thanks. From where should I drag and drop?

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly stealing Phil's answer from Sparx' forum (since he is not registered with SO):

> Simply put you cannot use to Wizard to add a model structure to your MDG
>
> Instead you have to edit the MTS file
>
> Check out the PDF user guide for EA v 11 beginning at page 1577

And to complete with KP's reply:

> Very briefly, what you need to do is add your XMI file to the "ModelPatterns" folder in EA's install path, and then add a "ModelTemplates" block to your MDG Technology XML file to tell EA where to find the XMI (or better, add the "ModelTemplates" block to your MTS file so it gets added to your technology when you build it). Open up some of the MDG Technologies in a text editor to see how we've done it.

Comment: @ThomasKillian, Thanks for updaing me about the answers. I really got confused with all advise. Can you please provide a link to a simple step-by-step guide how to create such MDG ( or maybe model profile?) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I once made a write-up here: http://community.sparxsystems.com/tutorials/552-24intro-to-creating-a-mdg-file There's also an intro from a "tiger team" somewhere in BeNeLux (can't recall where exactly). There is quite a bit "distributed knowledge" you need...